# FMX Edit inverts selection when moving mouse too far away

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I am facing a strange issue that I can reproduce with a vanilla FMX Form.

First I place an Edit, set the horizontal alignment in TextSettings to Center or Trailing, and run the application. If I start selecting some text and move the mouse far enough to the right, the selection inverts. In fact, it seems like the required distance from the right edge of the edit is exactly the same as the distance from the end of the selection to that edge.

Here's a gif to illustrate the issue:

[image: GIF]

Does anybody know what is going on there? I have a hard time imagining this is by design. Any ideas for a workaround / fix would be appreciated.